# php date time showing 1970 after adding hours to it

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I have a variable `$datetime` and when I print it I get: `2015-04-20 20:00:00`. 
Which as far as I can see is in the format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

I'm trying to add 5 hours to this time so I'm using:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 hours', $datetime));
```

Which is outputting: `1970-01-01 04:33:35` and I can't see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument for [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) needs to be a valid timestamp, you in your example:

```
strtotime('+5 hours', $datetime)
```

should be:

```
strtotime('+5 hours', strtotime($datetime))
```

Comment: pfft I should of spotted that thank you very much.